# Calculation of the nth Fibonacci number using HashTableMap

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement the method fibCalc2 for calculation of nth Fibonacci number, but I'm getting the null pointer exception and I don't know how to go further. Is my solution make sense? Any help will be appreciated.

Note: HashTableMap is also implemented by myself, so it is different from the Java's implementation.

**Update:** NullPointerException on the last line of the code

Here is the code:

```
private static int callCount2;
private static Map<Integer, Long> ansMap = new LLQHashTableMap(10);



public static long fibCalc2(int n) {
    if(n == 0 ||n == 1) return n;
    if(ansMap.getSize() <= 2){
        ansMap.define(0, (long) 0);
        ansMap.define(1, (long) 1);
    }
    long tempVal1, tempVal2;
    try {
        long temp = ansMap.remove(n);
        ansMap.define(n, temp);
    } catch (Exception ex){

        try {
            long temp = ansMap.remove(n-1);
            ansMap.define(n, temp);
            tempVal1 = ansMap.getValue(n-1);
        } catch (Exception ex1){
            tempVal1 = fibCalc2(n-1);
        }
        try {
            long temp = ansMap.remove(n-2);
            ansMap.define(n, temp);
            tempVal2 = ansMap.getValue(n-2);
        } catch (Exception ex1){
            tempVal2 = fibCalc2(n-2);
        }
        ansMap.define(n, tempVal1+tempVal2);
    }
    callCount2++;
    return ansMap.getValue(n);
}
```

interface of my Map:

```
package adt;

import impl.KeyValuePair;

/**
 * A generic map
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public interface Map<K, V> {

    /**
     * Adds a new key-value mapping to the map, which will
     * replace a previous key-value mapping that has the
     * same key, if it exists
     *
     * @param key of the key-value pair to be added
     * @param value of the key-value pair to be added
     */
    public void define(K key, V value);

    /**
     * Returns the value associated with the given key
     * in the map, if one exists, or null if the key is 
     * not in the map
     *
     * @param key whose value we want to return
     * @return value associated with the given key
     */
    public V getValue(K key);

    /**
     * Removes the key-value pair from the map that has
     * the given key value, and returns the associated value 
     * if it exists; if the key is not in the map, the map
     * remains unchanged, and null is returned
     *
     * @param key of the key-value pair that we want to remove
     * @return value associated with the given key before removal
     */
    public V remove(K key);

    /**
     * Removes and returns some key-value pair from the map, 
     * if the map is not empty; if the map is empty, an 
     * exception is thrown
     *
     * @return some key-value pair from the map
     * @throws Exception if the map is empty
     */
    public KeyValuePair<K, V> removeAny() throws Exception;

    /**
     * @return the number of key-value pairs in the map
     */
    public int getSize();

    /**
     * Removes all key-value pairs from the map
     */
    public void clear();

    /**
     * @return a String representation of the map
     */
    @Override
    public String toString();
}
```

Comment: Could you add the StackTrace of the Exception, please? It tells you in which line the error happens.

Comment: @makusw ```Null Pointer Exception``` on the last return statement

Comment: Why do you have logic in the catch blocks? You should be printing `ex.printStackTrace()` there, not call other methods.

Comment: How can you get an exception on the final `return` stmt if the immediately preceding `printf`, which executes the exact same expression, succeeded.  Unless your map somehow corrupts itself when you call its `getValue` method...

Comment: @KevinAnderson owh, sorry, that was a debugging stuff, I have removed it from the code

Comment: We need the complete stacktrace. This is the tool to use to do debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE happens on the line

```
long temp = ansMap.remove(n);
```

when n = 2 because remove(n) will return null and you can’t assign null to a primitive type variable.

Comment: But I have write the logic in catch block, so it will catch this Exception, isn't it?

Comment: And what is the state of your map after the exception? You don’t base your design on exceptions being thrown, it’s a very bad habit.